# computing permutation of specific bits in a number

Tags: c++, permutation, combinatorics, hamming-distance

As part of my master thesis, I get a number (e.g. 5 bits) with 2 significant bits (2nd and 4th). This means for example `x1x0x`, where `$x \in {0,1}$` (x could be 0 or 1) and `1,0` are bits with fixed values.

My first task is to compute all the combinations of the above given number , `2^3 = 8`. This is called `S_1` group.

Then I need to compute 'S_2' group and this is all the combinations of the two numbers `x0x0x` and `x1x1x`(this means one mismatch in the significant bits), this should give us `$\bin{2}{1} * 2^3 = 2 * 2^3 = 16`.

**EDIT**
Each number, `x1x1x` and `x0x0x`, is different from the *Original* number, `x1x0x`, at one significant bit.

Last group, `S_3`, is of course two mismatches from the significant bits, this means, all the numbers which pass the form `x0x1x`, 8 possibilities.

The computation could be computed recursively or independently, that is not a problem.

I would be happy if someone could give a starting point for these computations, since what I have is not so efficient.

**EDIT**
 Maybe I chose my words wrongly, using *significant bits*. What I meant to say is that a specific places in a five bits number the bit are fixed. Those places I defined as *specific bits*.

**EDIT**
I saw already 2 answers and it seems I should have been clearer. What I am more interested in, is finding the numbers `x0x0x`, `x1x1x` and `x0x1x` with respect that this is a simply example. In reality, the group `S_1` (in this example `x1x0x`) would be built with at least 12 bit long numbers and could contain 11 significant bits. Then I would have 12 groups...

If something is still not clear please ask ;)

Comment: I may not understand but if the second and fourth bits are significant, isn't the third bit significant as well?

Comment: So do you want to obtain the number of permutations adhering to your constraints or a list of them?

Comment: I don't actually understand the question. What is the actual *end goal* of all of this?

Comment: A number x0x0x will differ from a number x1x1x by 2 significant bits according to your definition, yet you say it means there is one mismatch in the significant bits.  Which is wrong?

Comment: @Argote, the 3 groups could be computed at the same time. The result at the end should be that 32 possible numbers (5 bits) would be placed in the correct groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string format = "x1x0x";

    unsigned int sigBits = 0;
    unsigned int sigMask = 0;
    unsigned int numSigBits = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < format.length(); ++i)
    {
        sigBits <<= 1;
        sigMask <<= 1;
        if (format[i] != 'x')
        {
            sigBits |= (format[i] - '0');
            sigMask |= 1;
            ++numSigBits;
        }
    }

    unsigned int numBits = format.length();
    unsigned int maxNum = (1 << numBits);

    vector<vector<unsigned int> > S;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numSigBits; i++)
        S.push_back(vector<unsigned int>());

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxNum; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int changedBits = (i & sigMask) ^ sigBits;

        unsigned int distance = 0;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numBits; j++)
        {
            if (changedBits & 0x01)
                ++distance;
            changedBits >>= 1;
        }

        S[distance].push_back(i);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numSigBits; ++i)
    {
        cout << dec << "Set with distance " << i << endl;
        vector<unsigned int>::iterator iter = S[i].begin();
        while (iter != S[i].end())
        {
            cout << hex << showbase << *iter << endl;
            ++iter;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`sigMask` has a 1 where all your specific bits are.  `sigBits` has a 1 wherever your specific bits are 1.  `changedBits` has a 1 wherever the current value of `i` is different from `sigBits`.  `distance` counts the number of bits that have changed.  This is about as efficient as you can get without precomputing a lookup table for the distance calculation.

Comment: i liked the idea, but `sigBits` and `sigMask` need to be as well computed... the question is how do i do that, when what i know is only `x1x0x`?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it doesn't actually matter what the fixed-bit values are, only that they're fixed. `xyxyx`, where y is fixed and x isn't, will always yield 8 potentials. The potential combinations of the two groups where `y` varies between them will always be a simple multiplication- that is, for each state that the first may be in, the second may be in each state.

Answer (score 0):

Use bit logic.

```
//x1x1x
if(01010 AND test_byte) == 01010) //--> implies that the position where 1s are are 1.
```

There's probably a number-theoretic solution, but, this is very simple.

This needs to be done with a fixed-bit integer type. Some dynamic languages (python for example), will extend bits out if they think it's a good idea.

This is not hard, but it is time consuming, and TDD would be particularly appropriate here.